# check the byte length before sending back to severs in socket programming in python

Tags: python, sockets

My client sends a message to server. The server collects the message `16 byte`s each time and when it receives anything less than `16 bytes`, it returns the message (after concatenation) back to the client.

Here is the code from `server.py:`

```
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM,socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

    sock.bind(address)
    sock.listen(1)

    try:
        while True:
            conn,add=sock.accept()
            addr=(conn,add)
            print add
            try:
                data = ''
                while True:

                    recvdata=conn.recv(16)
                    print recvdata
                    data+=recvdata
                    if len(recvdata)<16:
                        print >>log_buffer,"sending data"
                        conn.sendall(data)
                        break


            finally:
                conn.close()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sock.close()
```

The code works well for messages above 16 and less than `16 byte` length, when it is exactly 16 or mutliples of 16, it is not sending back to client. how do I fix for this?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't say anything about what it should do at exactly a multiple of 16.
The code you posted will not send it back though.
Change `<` to `<=`.

`<` means less than.

`<=` means less than or equal to (multiple of).

Code:

```
if len(recvdata)<=16:
    print >>log_buffer,"sending data"
    conn.sendall(data)
    break
```

---

Edit:

If you are just getting the message and returning whole bytes you can do the following:

```
while True:
    conn,add=sock.accept()
    addr=(conn,add)
    print add
    try:
        recvdata=conn.recv(2048) #however much you need

        wholebytes = len(recvdata) / 16 # get the number of whole bytes

        # loop to send messages of length 16 with whole bytes
        for i in range(wholebytes):
            data = recvdata[i*16:(i+1)*16]
            print >>log_buffer,"sending data"
            conn.sendall(data)

        break
```

Comment: I do not want to send all the message is collected. what if I have 32 bytes, I will send two messages back.

Comment: if you have 32 bytes you will send 2 messages since you only receive 16 bytes at a time.

Comment: but I am breaking of the loop, if I have 32 bytes, I will send first 16 bytes, but I am breaking immediately before I collect the remaining 16 and send it back

Comment: don't break then. or only break on `<` 16 bytes.

Comment: its slightly complicated than it is. what if the last bytes I get is exactly 16 length, it neither breaks or sends back the message. (the exact question above)

Comment: The goal is to collect `entire bytes` and send them in `one packet`. for non-mulitples of 16, it works, because, I check for byte length to be less than 16 and if it happens, it indicates that I am received the last set of bytes. I then send the entire message back

Comment: with the change i suggested it will both break and send back a message. if you don't want to break then put another if statement in, if you do want to break then keep it as i have suggested. Most likely if you get 32 bytes you will send two messages and then continue to receive if you don't break on 16. The only way you can know if you are truly finished is if you collect a large amount of bytes and loop through till you hit the end and send all the whole bytes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44918/discussion-between-user1988876-and-serdalis)

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately this work computer won't allow stack-overflow chat. I'll post an answer that I think is what you are trying to do.

Comment: that is a neat solution! what if the `data` you are receiving is more than 2048? you have actually removed inner while loop, and assumed that you call collect all the message at once correct?

Comment: correct, if you wanted more than 2048 bytes you could keep the while loop running, I usually just do that in my programs and give it a separate thread.